# How to excecute a stored procedure taking table as argument one by one?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[JNLOBJLIST] AS TABLE(
    [Journal_Master_Id] [int] NULL,
    [strTransRefNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dateGLTransDate] [date] NULL,
    [decGLTransAmount] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [strGLTransRemark] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [guidCompanybranchId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [intGLAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [intFiscalYearId] [int] NULL,
    [boolGLIsDebit] [binary](1) NULL,
    [strPerson] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [inttblReferenceId] [int] NULL,
    [decGLTransAmount2] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [strJournalmemo] [varchar](50) NULL)
GO
```

and SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insertGl_transtemp2] 
@LIST [dbo].JNLOBJLIST READONLY

AS
DECLARE @id int

BEGIN

INSERT INTO tbl_GL_Trans_Detailstemp
                    ( trans_ref_number
                    , GL_trans_date
                    , GL_trans_amount
                    , GL_trans_remark
                    , company_branch_id
                    , GL_Account_id
                    , fiscal_year_id
                    , IsDebit
                    , Person
                    , tbl_reference_Id)

SELECT              strTransRefNumber
                    , dateGLTransDate
                    , decGLTransAmount
                    , strGLTransRemark
                    , guidCompanybranchId
                    , intGLAccountId
                    , intFiscalYearId
                    , boolGLIsDebit
                    , strPerson
                    , inttblReferenceId FROM @LIST

SET @id = (SELECT MAX(GL_trans_id)
FROM   tbl_GL_Trans_Detailstemp)


UPDATE    tbl_Gl_account
SET GL_Balance = GL_Balance + (SELECT decGLTransAmount2 FROM @LIST)
WHERE (GL_Account_id = (SELECT intGLAccountId FROM @LIST))

DECLARE @Journal_Master_Id int
DECLARE @Trans_Id int
DECLARE @Amount decimal
DECLARE @Memo varchar(50)

SET @Journal_Master_Id=(SELECT Journal_Master_Id FROM @LIST)
SET @Trans_Id=(@id)
SET @Amount=(SELECT decGLTransAmount FROM @LIST)
SET @Memo=(SELECT strJournalmemo FROM @LIST)

INSERT INTO tbl_Journal_Details
    (Journal_Master_Id, Trans_Id, Amount, Memo)
VALUES     (@Journal_Master_Id,@Trans_Id,@Amount,@Memo)

END
RETURN
```

actually after my first insert statement , i need the value of tbl_GL_Trans_Detailstemp's
primary key GL_trans_id to insert it into next table...

So if the type table @LIST has many rows(say 5), i need all the statements to get executed one by one(as a loop works)

But as far i have checked the first insert statement works as a whole at first, then only next statements get excecuted. How can i overcome this?

To be more precise, i need a solution which uses following logic

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insertGl_transtemp2] 
@LIST [dbo].JNLOBJLIST READONLY,
@COUNT int
AS
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @rowcount int=0
WHILE @rowcount<@COUNT
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tbl_GL_Trans_Detailstemp
                    ( trans_ref_number
                    , GL_trans_date
                    , GL_trans_amount
                    , GL_trans_remark
                    , company_branch_id
                    , GL_Account_id
                    , fiscal_year_id
                    , IsDebit
                    , Person
                    , tbl_reference_Id)

SELECT              @rowcount.strTransRefNumber
                    , @rowcount.dateGLTransDate
                    , @rowcount.decGLTransAmount
                    , @rowcount.strGLTransRemark
                    , @rowcount.guidCompanybranchId
                    , @rowcount.intGLAccountId
                    , @rowcount.intFiscalYearId
                    , @rowcount.boolGLIsDebit
                    , @rowcount.strPerson
                    , @rowcount.inttblReferenceId FROM @LIST

SET @id = (SELECT MAX(GL_trans_id)
FROM   tbl_GL_Trans_Detailstemp)


UPDATE    tbl_Gl_account
SET GL_Balance = GL_Balance + (SELECT @rowcount.decGLTransAmount2 FROM @LIST)
WHERE (GL_Account_id = (SELECT @rowcount.intGLAccountId FROM @LIST))

DECLARE @Journal_Master_Id int
DECLARE @Trans_Id int
DECLARE @Amount decimal
DECLARE @Memo varchar(50)

SET @Journal_Master_Id=(SELECT @rowcount.Journal_Master_Id FROM @LIST)
SET @Trans_Id=(@id)
SET @Amount=(SELECT @rowcount.decGLTransAmount FROM @LIST)
SET @Memo=(SELECT @rowcount.strJournalmemo FROM @LIST)

INSERT INTO tbl_Journal_Details
    (Journal_Master_Id, Trans_Id, Amount, Memo)
VALUES     (@Journal_Master_Id,@Trans_Id,@Amount,@Memo)

SET @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
END
RETURN
```

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to avoid a loop and use the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) from the first `INSERT` later on in the query. The example below is based on a guess that `@list.strTransRefNumber` is `UNIQUE`. Even if it's not `UNIQUE` it may still be possible for you to refactor the `JOIN` in the last `INSERT` as you know how things are related etc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insertGl_transtemp2] 
@list [dbo].JNLOBJLIST READONLY
AS    
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
        DECLARE @inserted TABLE ( id INT NOT NULL, strTransRefNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL )

        INSERT INTO tbl_GL_Trans_Detailstemp
          ( trans_ref_number, GL_trans_date, GL_trans_amount, GL_trans_remark, company_branch_id
            , GL_Account_id, fiscal_year_id, IsDebit, Person, tbl_reference_Id ) 
        OUTPUT INSERTED.GL_trans_id, INSERTED.trans_ref_number INTO @inserted 
        SELECT strTransRefNumber, dateGLTransDate, decGLTransAmount, strGLTransRemark
           , guidCompanybranchId, intGLAccountId, intFiscalYearId, boolGLIsDebit
           , strPerson, inttblReferenceId 
        FROM @list

        -- refactored it to use a join which i think is what you need here
        UPDATE a
        SET a.GL_Balance = a.GL_Balance + l.decGLTransAmount2
        FROM tbl_Gl_account a
        JOIN @list l ON l.intGLAccountId = a.GL_Account_id

        INSERT INTO tbl_Journal_Details
            (Journal_Master_Id, Trans_Id, Amount, Memo)
        SELECT l.Journal_Master_Id, i.id, l.decGLTransAmount, l.strJournalmemo
        FROM @list l
        JOIN @inserted i ON i.strTransRefNumber = l.strTransRefNumber
    COMMIT
END
RETURN
```

Comment: 'OUTPUT INSERTED.GL_trans_id, INSERTED.trans_ref_number INTO @inserted 
' invalid syntax near INSERTED... This solution will satisfy my needs. Can you please figure it out for me? Also please tell me what will be the return value for this whole querry?(just 1 or 0 indicating the success?)

Comment: Apologies I have fixed the error. The procedure as is will just return 1 or 0

Comment: Thankyou for your support. The solution You gave me works, and my problem is solved.